# -shell-escape does not work

Tags: tikz-external, capacity

When running `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %filename%.tex`

It gives:

```
Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error interaction=batchmode -jobname "tikzfiles/nistco2-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{nistco2}\input{nistco2}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'tikzfiles/nistco2-figure0' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed? Error messages can be found in 'tikzfiles/nistco2-figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.
```

*-figure.log file contains only

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].
```

And min working example is

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=10mm, top=15mm, right=10mm, bottom=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external} 
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikzfiles/]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table [x=v, y=p, col sep=comma] {trt.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

File `trt.csv` contains about 2K-3K pairs of coordinates
For example

```
1,1
1.1,1.2
1.213233,1.2323
```

This file you can find at https://wdfiles.ru/d54a24

I usually use TeXMaker, but it reproduces in command line

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.3.1
Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.01
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: That is not really minimal. And it is also not an example as we don't have the csv-files and so can't test.

Comment: Check the `tikzfiles/nistco2-figure0.log` to see if it contains any error messages.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ in contains `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry. I've minimized it and added link to a file

Comment: so you answered your own question, if the run fills tex's main memory and doesn't complete then that means shell-escape did work and ran tex, it's just the tex produced no output, so the problem is unrelated to shell-escape

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't understand. Without plot it contains much text, it must produces anything. Yes, it says, that job produces nothing like .png or same, but why then?

Comment: your plot is producing `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000]` that is a fatal error tex ran out of memory and produced no output,  do you really need 3K sets of points to produce a readable pot? can you not filter the dataset before plotting? what happens (without shell escape) if you just make a small document with just that plot, do you get same error (I would expect so)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, without shell-escape I get the same. Is there really a limit on the amount of memory?  What is he for?  Naturally, I understand that there is a RAM limit, but my number of points clearly does not fill it all

Comment: tex does not do dynamic memory allocation (you can try using luatex, which does) you can increas the limit in texmf.cnf  up to some compile limits.  The amount of memory you have on your machine is not relevant here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ok, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will share the setup I used to process 10k to 30k data points generated by R  querying statistical databases. (Windows Operating System, 8192 MB memory)

Start editing `pdflatex.ini`:

Using `MikTeX`, in my PC it is located in

`C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Local\Programs\MikTeX\miktex\config`

In other installations it might be `C:\Programs Files\MikTeX\miktex\config`

Add at the beginning of the file (I found this values by trial and error, I do not know if everything is needed)

```
main_memory=230000000
save_size=79999
extra_mem_bot=79999999 
extra_mem_top=79999999 
font_mem_size=799999
pool_size=39999999
buf_size=29999999
EnableWrite18=p
stack-size=200000
max-strings=79999999
```

Create the directory `tikzfiles` in your working directory and run my example to get

[image: a]

and these files in the `./tikzfiles` directory

[image: b]

```
%%% This is file TestExternalize.tex

% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=10mm, top=15mm, right=10mm, bottom=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[%
up to date check={simple},
prefix=./tikzfiles/]% Folder needs to be created before compiling

\tikzset{external/system call={%
        pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape
        -halt-on-error -shell-escape -interaction=batchmode
        -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot table [x=v, y=p, col sep=comma] {trt.csv};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Check that the second time  the output it is immediate.

This is the end of the `.log` file

```
{C:/Users/SD/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/pdftex/config/pdftex.map} <./tikzfiles/TestExternalize-figure0.pdf>] (TestExternalize.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
22489 strings out of 479321
602372 string characters out of 39607058
81007926 words of memory out of 83725312
39608 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
403728 words of font info for 28 fonts, out of 799999 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
102i,5n,103p,740b,609s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,29999999b,79999s
<C:/Users/SD/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi12.pfb>
<C:/Users/SD/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb>
Output written on TestExternalize.pdf (1 page, 266897 bytes).
PDF statistics:
25 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
18 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: +1: Thanks for sharing. I always forget what worked for me in the past so it's good to have an example reference.